# How to fix plt.show() and plt.savefig errors when increasing DPI?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dpi

I wrote a code which requires some manual formatting of the legend to get what I want. Based on [a question I posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782592/how-to-put-multiple-symbols-with-the-same-label-on-the-same-line-in-the-legend) and some more googling, I got the legend to look exactly how I want when it displays using plt.show(). Unfortunately, now when I save the image using plt.savefig(dpi=300), the legend gets totally screwed up. It looks like when I save it from the plt.show window it is at 200dpi, but I would like to save it at at least 300 or more dpi.

[What plots when I use plt.show is this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLVqQ.png)

[But when I save it in plt.savefig and change the dpi to 300, it's this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd1VU.png)

I see posts, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906365/matplotlib-savefig-plots-different-from-show), that say there is a resolution difference between plt.show and plt.savefig, but I don't understand how to actually resolve the issue for me. I have tried setting the figure size, but once I change the dpi in savefig it screws it up again.  I have also tried adding bbox_inches='tight' into savefig, it doesn't make a difference.

Here is a code to test it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple

x = np.arange(3)
y = np.arange(3)

c1= plt.plot(x,y, color = 'blue'    , label= "blue")
c2 = plt.plot(x,y, color = 'green'   , label= "green")
c3 = plt.plot(x,y, color = 'red'     , label= "red")
c4 = plt.plot(x,y, color = 'magenta' , label= "magenta")



p1 = plt.scatter(x,y, color = 'blue')
p2 = plt.scatter(x,y, color = 'green')
p3 = plt.scatter(x,y, color = 'red')
p4 = plt.scatter(x,y, color = 'magenta')

t1 = plt.scatter(x,y, color = 'blue',  facecolors='none')
t2 = plt.scatter(x,y, color = 'green',  facecolors='none')
t3 = plt.scatter(x,y, color = 'red',  facecolors='none')
t4 = plt.scatter(x,y, color = 'magenta',  facecolors='none')

l1 = plt.legend(handlelength = 0, bbox_to_anchor=(1, .5, 0,0), loc ='center right')  
llines = l1.get_texts()
llines[0].set_color('blue')
llines[1].set_color('green')
llines[2].set_color('red')
llines[3].set_color('magenta')

shift = max([t.get_window_extent().width for t in l1.get_texts()]) 
for t in l1.get_texts():
    t.set_ha('right') 
    t.set_position((shift,0))

l2 = plt.legend([(p1, p2, p3, p4), (t1, t2, t3, t4)], ['tomatoes', 'potatoes'],
       scatterpoints=1, numpoints=1, loc = 'center right',bbox_to_anchor=(1, .3, 0,0),  
       handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None)})

plt.gca().add_artist(l1)

shift2 = max([t2.get_window_extent().width for t2 in l2.get_texts()])  
for t2 in l2.get_texts():
    t2.set_ha('right') # ha is alias for horizontalalignment
    t2.set_position((shift2,0))   


plt.show()
filename_save = "testfile"
plt.savefig(filename_save, dpi = 300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Any ideas? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You shift the text by some *pixels*. Obviously the amount to shift them needs to be different for different dpi settings. I might hence suggest to no work in pixels when targeting different dpi outputs.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing that out. that part for the shift was some line of code that I copied and pasted from somewhere and didn't really understand how it worked. i'll see if i can adapt it to not work in pixels.